# The question list's "actioned X time ago" alignment is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

The “asked/answered/edited X time ago” messages on the question list are always right-aligned. Today that right alignment seems to be missing, except for when they word wrap to the next line.

It definitely doesn't seem deliberately like this; there's no space at all between the tags and attribution.

[image]

Comment: We can hotfix this ourselves: *use more, longer tags*.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Genius!

Comment: MSE report of the same bug: [Alignment issue in the “Top Questions” page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366481/681403)

Comment: This seems to have been fixed so I'm marking it completed, though I don't think there's any info out on it yet. Anyone interested is probably best of following the MSE question